# boost::optional has changed an implicit function

Tags: c++, boost, option-type

I am using VS2008 and has just changed from boost 1.51 to 1.61. Unfortunately boost decided to change the `boost::optional<T>` and make the cast from optional to bool explicit i.e. the snippet below is not valid anymore

```
boost::optional<TYPE> optType;
TYPE t = default;
if (optType)
    t = optType;
```

You must explicitly cast the `optType` to `bool` to make this work.

Even more unfortunate is the fact that this still compiles (with the wrong result ofc), and I am unable to detect where it is used. Does anyone know of any (even intrusive) methods to detect those places.

I tried to mark the implicit cast as deprecated in boosts 1.51 hpp-file but for some reason the compiler does not show any warnings.

The amount of code I have to look through is several hundred thousand rows that's why I need this.

Comment: There is no problem with `explicit` in the above code. Maybe the explicit conversion to bool you use does something other than `operator bool`.

Comment: Yep, an `explicit operator bool()` is required to work in an `if` condition. If it didn't work then it wouldn't compile, so _"Even more unfortunate is the fact that this still compiles (with the wrong result ofc)"_ doesn't make sense. Please provide complete code showing the problem (preferably without misusing the keyword `default`!)

Comment: IIRC, VS2008 does not support `explicit` on the conversion operators. Boost is probably defaulting back to a "safe bool" of some sort. To see what the operator finally looks like, you could look to dump the pre-processed file out (based on a MCVE) of some sort - and then annotate that in the boost source.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular snippet, you could simply write

```
boost::optional<TYPE> optType;
TYPE t = default;
if (optType)
    t = true;
```

However, did you mean to get the `TYPE` value?

```
if (optType)
    t = *optType;
```

You can also simply to

```
t = optType.get_value_or(default);
```